# How to solve DbNull system.cast value is not valid in c# vb.net?

Tags: c#, sql

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 122:       string TeacherFname = (string)ResultSet["teacherfname"];
Line 123:       string TeacherLname = (string)ResultSet["teacherlname"];
Line 124:       DateTime TeacherHireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ResultSet["hiredate"]);
Line 125:       decimal TeacherSalary = Convert.ToDecimal(ResultSet["salary"]);  
Line 126:
```

I need to add Datetime in database

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags to your question to get more views. 9/10 you'll just get downvotes.

Comment: You say _"need add datetime in database"_ - what does this mean? The rest of your question seems to be about handling a null value coming from the database, but then you have that at the end. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you read a `NULL` value from.a nullable column in the database, the result with be a value of `DBNull`. You need to handle it. Consider use some sort of database mapping technology (Entity Framework, Dapper,  using a DataSet). Doing this by hand is tedious

Comment: You need to provide ALL the relevant information. What type is `ResultSet`? It is presumably a `DataRow` or a data reader but the best solution depends on which.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With reference types (like string) use the as operator

```
string TeacherFname = ResultSet["teacherfname"] as string;
```

if you are using C# 8 or later use

```
string? TeacherFname = ResultSet["teacherfname"] as string;
```

Or you can use `var` and let the compiler infer the type which works with earlier versions as well

```
var TeacherFname = ResultSet["teacherfname"] as string;
```

For value types like `DateTime` and `decimal` you may want to use `Nullable<DateTime>` or `Nullable<decimal>` (shorthand `DateTime?` and `decimal?`

update: thank you guys to help me its solved because i removed null value in database.